# Android: Order of layers in result drawable is different each time when i call function

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawable

i have following code:

```
public Drawable getMergedIcon(Drawable origIcon) {  
    Bitmap underlayBitmap = null, overlayBitmap = null;
    if (isSupportUnderlays()) {
        int overlayId = r.nextInt(Underlays.size());
        underlayBitmap = Underlays.get(overlayId);
        if(Overlays.size() == Underlays.size()) {
            overlayBitmap = Overlays.get(overlayId);
        }
        if(underlayBitmap == null) {
            return origIcon;
        }

        boolean needResize = false;
        int targetWidth, targetHeight;
        Bitmap iconBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) origIcon).getBitmap();

        if(iconBitmap.getHeight() > underlayBitmap.getHeight()) {
            targetWidth = iconBitmap.getWidth();
            targetHeight = iconBitmap.getHeight();
            needResize = true;
        } else {
            targetWidth = underlayBitmap.getWidth();
            targetHeight = underlayBitmap.getHeight();
        }


        Paint paint = new Paint();

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, iconBitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

        if(!needResize) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(underlayBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(underlayBitmap, targetWidth,targetHeight, false), 0, 0, paint);
        }
        int left = (targetHeight - (int) (targetHeight * iconScale)) / 2;
        int top = (targetWidth - (int) (targetWidth * iconScale)) / 2;
        iconBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(iconBitmap, (int) (targetWidth * iconScale),(int) (targetHeight * iconScale), false);
        canvas.drawBitmap(iconBitmap, left, top, paint);

        if(overlayBitmap != null) {
            if(!needResize) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(overlayBitmap, targetWidth,targetHeight, false), 0, 0, paint);
            }
        }
        canvas.save();

        BitmapDrawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), result);
        return icon; 
    }
    return origIcon;
}
```

it takes random bitmap from overlays and underlays and places icon between it
but when i call this function layers is missed randomly. 
f.e. on first call i have underlay and icon, on second overlay and icon and etc
i always have icon, but with only one layer(underlay or overlay) and never with bot of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was workable, was my stupid mistake...
I just placed wrong drawables in arrays.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please post an answer with a (short) answer what exactly was wrong. You can accept that answer. This answer does not provide any information about what was wrong and therefore will not be of any use for someone that finds this question later.